# Timestamp Not Returned in Batch

Tags: batch-file, scripting, cmd, timestamp

I am trying to run a batch file to update some software if the `exe` file is timestamped before the most recent version. To do this, I am using a well known `for` loop.

When I do this:

```
set file=%AppData%\spark\spark.properties
for %%a in (%file%) do set olddate=%%~ta
echo %olddate%
```

A timestamp is returned.
When I run it like this:

```
set spark_exe=%ProgramFiles%\Spark\Spark.exe
for %%a in (%spark_exe%) do set olddate=%%~ta
echo %olddate%
```

A timestamp is not returned. (Nor for any other files in that folder)
If I run:

```
set spark_exe=%ProgramFiles%\Spark\Spark.exe
for %%a in (%spark_exe%) do set fqp=%%~fa
echo %fqp%
```

I get the fully qualified path.

So... I can use SOME expansion variables.. but not others... why?... how?... help?

Thanks :)

Comment: try to use quotes -> `set "spark_exe=%ProgramFiles%\Spark\Spark.exe"` and `for %%a in ("%spark_exe%") do set olddate=%%~ta`

Comment: No change... I've even tried putting the fqp between parenthesis with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I tried the batch code below and it worked:

```
@echo off
if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Spark\Spark.exe" (
    set "spark_exe=%ProgramFiles%\Spark\Spark.exe"
) else if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Spark\Spark.exe" (
    set "spark_exe=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Spark\Spark.exe"
) else (
    echo Error: Could not find Spark.exe
    pause
    goto :EOF
)
for %%a in ("%spark_exe%") do echo %%~ta
set "spark_exe="
```

I replaced also `%%~ta` by `%%~fa` to get name of file with path instead of last modification date and it worked, too.

Then I used Process Monitor of Sysinternals and logged the file system accesses on `Spark.exe`.

I could see that `cmd.exe` makes two [IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548658.aspx) requests of type **FileBothDirectoryInformation** to check if the file exists and get full name of the file on using in batch file `%%~fa`.

There are the same two IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY requests with `%%~ta` in batch file. But additionally there is also a [IRP_MJ_QUERY_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549283.aspx) request which is different to IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY as it is done with a file handle.

Is it possible that `Spark.exe` is currently created by the compiler when the batch file is executed and therefore any access on file is denied for any other application like `cmd.exe`?

I suggest to use also Process Monitor of Sysinternals and define **Path ends with Spark.exe** as **include** filter. Then run your batch file. Look now in Process Monitor if you can see any *access denied* in the log.